# What does this mean? 'span[class^=someclass]'

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, socket.io, setinterval

This is some code someone wrote for a socket.io chat site. First, what does 
'span[class^=someclass]' mean? Second, if a variable is set to a function and I want to turn it on and off with a button, can I just switch it off by setting it to false? Thanks!

```
ANTIAFK = setInterval(function() {
    $("#userlist").find('span[class^=userlist]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).html() == CLIENT.name && $(this).css('font-style') == "italic") {
            socket.emit("chatMsg", {
                msg: '/afk'
            });
            return;
        }
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

> It is the attribute starts-with selector`^`

.

`'span[class^=userlist]'` will select all the span element whose class starts with `userlist`.

There are other similar kind of selectors as well.

1. $ is the ends with selector.
2. ^ is starts with selector.
3. '*'  is the contains selector.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute Starts With Selector `[name^=”value”]`

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   beginning exactly with a given string.

[**More Details**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

In your case where `class` starts with `userlist`